# Is it possible to push media to Azure from web browser?

Tags: azure-media-services

1) I'm researching the technology I can use for a browser applicaton that streams video. It should capture video from webcam and push it to service where it's stored and can be watched later. One of the (possible?) options is Azure Media Services. But after a quick look at the documentation it seems that it's not possible to use pure modern browser without plugins. Am I correct? If no, can you please give some links to github projects or an example of code to look at?

2) Another possible technology option is Amazon Kinesis Video Streams (looks lite the best solution I came up with so far), but maybe you can recommend some other cloud services?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently the short answer is no. 
WebRTC is the right solution for broadcasting from a browser. That's the only protocol for live streaming that will be "somewhat" widely supported in modern browsers like latest Chrome.

AMS does not yet support receiving WebRTC. We only support RTMP and Smooth ingest right now (Chunked MP4)

As far as I'm aware, Kinesis also expects you to send chunked MKV (like chunked MP4 but a less popular container format), which would need a browser plugin or javascript library to support. I don't see any Producer library from them in Javascript.

WebRTC is your answer - but to catch that in the cloud, you may need to look at other solutions that run in an Azure Container.  There are a bunch of 3rd party solutions out there for WebRTC.

Comment: It seems like I need some backend for both AMS and Kinesis, because browser can't post xhr to another origin (am I wrong?).

Comment: And about WebRTC - what's the benefit of using it instead of getUserMedia / mediaRecorder / XMLHttpRequest and some simple backend which proxies chunked mkv/mp4 to the cloud? If I want fancy WebRTC, I will need at least 3 servers running (WebRTC server, something that proxies webrtc stream into rtsp so it's compatibe with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-gstreamer-plugin.html and producer to push media to the cloud). Or is there a simplier solution?
But in this case media traffic still goes through my server, so I don't see any benefit from WebRTC.